# Database structure for scholar schedules saving subjects

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling

Im working on a tutorship project, and im having trouble deciding which is the best approach for saving students schedules in the database.

The information of the schedule is simple, it has subject, day of the week, and begin and end hour,

So i was wondering if is better to generate and save a whole calendar for all subjects and days from the current school calendar.

Im using a tool which helps me draw a calendar, i have to feed it with start and end date.

So it's kind of easier generate the whole calendar in the db.

The other way i thinks is just saving de Name of de day, and start and end hour, and generate a function that "fakes" the dates so i can load the calendar.

Thanks for reading and if i wasn't clear, sorry and pls comment

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following would be a normalized data structure:

Date

- Date
- Day of Week

Student

- Id
- Name
- Etc.

Class

- Id
- Name
- DefaultStartTime
- DefaultEndTime

ClassMember

- StudentId
- ClassId

ClassDefaultMeetingDays

- ClassId
- DayOfWeek

ClassInstance

- ClassId
- StartDateTime
- EndDateTime

Some of these tables are self-explanatory. Others likely need some clarification:

**ClassMember**

You have a many-to-many relationship between a Student and a Class (i.e. a student can take multiple classes and a class can have multiple students) For this, you'll need a (junction table)[https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/218734758-A-beginner-s-guide-to-many-to-many-relationships]

**ClassDefaultMeetingDays**

While you can store information like Start and End Time on the Class table, you'll actually need a separate table to store which days of the week a class meets as this is a one to many relationship.

**ClassInstance**

This is going to be the heart of your application as this is what you'll feed into your calendar app. The advantage of splitting this into a separate table is you can then edit it as needed. If you simply derive it from the Class, Date and ClassDefaultMeetingDays tables, you'll be crippled when class is cancelled because of a holiday, or when periods are shortened because of some special event. Building this out as a separate table allows you to populate this table using default logic (perhaps through a stored procedure?) and then you can give your users fine-tuned control to edit on ad hoc basis.

Further, semester to semester, the start and end values as well as Days of the Week will likely change for the same class, say ECON101. Storing the ClassInstances means that you can edit the Class Meeting Time information without losing historical data.

Query/Stored Procedure to populate default records in table:

```
DECLARE @SemesterStart date
DECLARE @SemesterEnd date

SELECT @SemesterStart = x
SELECT @SemesterEnd = y

SELECT INTO ClassInstance
Date.Date + CAST(Class.DefaultStartTime as datetime) AS StartDateTime
Date.Date + CAST(Class.DefaultStartTime as datetime) AS EndDateTime,
Class.Id AS ClassId
FROM Class
JOIN ClassDefaultMeetingDays
ON ClassDefaultMeetingDays.ClassId = Class.Id
JOIN Date ON
ClassDefaultMeetingDays.DayOfWeek = Date.DayOfWeek
AND Date.Date BETWEEN @SemesterStart AND @SemesterEnd
```

You can then make edits and query this table as needed!